# Delphi WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, синтаксический-анализ, загрузка, хостинг

Добрый день. Хочу сделать парсер для своего сайта. Допустим имею 10 программ и в каждой по 1-му ВебБраузеру(TWebBrowser), каждая в свою очередь с интервалом 1 сек загружает в свой браузер содержимое сайта www.мойсайт.ru страницу, потом я эту страницу загоняю в переменную и беру исходный код, что бы выбрать нужные данные. Так вот, каждую секунду 10 х 1 = 10 раз я отправляю запрос с одного IP с десяти программ на свой сайт. но вот после пару часов использования, я стал замечать что сайт который загружали ВебБроузеры переставал работать примерно на 1-н день. Может ли это быть из-за того что мои программы так часто туда обращаются ?(закачивают контент в ВебБроузеры)

> idHTTP я очень рад бы использовать,
> но если нету интернета, то зависает
> вся программа и через секунд 20-30
> "умирает",просто перестает реагировать
> на все, кнопки нажимаются,
> перетаскивание есть, а код не
> выполняется, даже button3.click =
> showmessage();. выноска в отдельный
> поток тоже ничего хорошего не дает.

P.S
Сайт 2-й и тоже не работает 1-н день после использования.
Сайты на бесплатном хостинге.

Comment: я предупреждал, что вас забанят. возможно сначала вам включают throttling каждый следующий запрос будет выполняться дольше. и с какого-то момента просто блокируют. будете дальше так баловаться удалят ваши сайты, хостеры не любят [DoS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-атака).

Comment: у меня нету цели ДДосить, да тут и так вроде понятно, что с моими знаниями даже думать о таком вредно. Только жаль хостинг этого не знает. Придется менять алгоритм программы

Comment: И зачем это каждую секунду? Раз в 30 сек - достаточно. Или кнопку сделать пускай юзер сам тыкает и обновляет "вне очереди".

Comment: вы когда писали вы сами осознавали что хотите?
Парсер? (штука которая просто по определенному алгоритму обрабатывает строку данных)
10 программ и в каждой браузер? (может вы имели в виду форму?)

> с интервалом 1 сек загружает в свой
> браузер содержимое сайта
> www.мойсайт.ru

и зачем каждую секунду открывать главную страницу сайта?

П.С. idHTTP как я понял из гугла компонент через который можно осуществлять авторизацию на сайте. Но каждую 1 секунду.... быть может вы все же объясните что вы сделать то хотите?

Comment: у вас в ответе больше вопросов по уточнению, чем ответов. А точнее ответа вообще нет.

Comment: 864к обращений в сутки на сайт - будь я машиной, я бы тоже вас забанил. А вообще пересмотрите свои цели и методы решения.